# Scala string interpolation with escaped quote fails

Tags: scala

```
scala> util.Properties.versionString
res11: String = version 2.11.2

scala> val a = ""
a: String = ""

scala> val a = "\""
a: String = "
```

So far so good. Now with string interpolation, it fails:

```
scala> val a = s"\""
<console>:1: error: unclosed string literal
       val a = s"\""
                   ^
```

Even after we provide closing escaped quote.

```
scala> val a = s"\"\""
<console>:7: error: value \ is not a member of String
       val a = s"\"\""
                   ^
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This appears to be a [known bug](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6476).

Note that you can get around it, at least for your case above, using triple quotes:

```
scala> val a = s"""""""" // seven quote characters all up!
a: String = "
```