# How to insert double quotes in s""?

Tags: scala, string-interpolation

I know that I can do string interpolation with `s""`, but how can I insert double quotes inside of `s""`?

```
scala> val x = "x"
x: String = x

scala> s""
res5: String = ""

scala> s"${x}"
res6: String = x

scala> s"${x}\""
<console>:1: error: unclosed string literal
       s"${x}\""
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scala string interpolation with escaped quote fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122564/scala-string-interpolation-with-escaped-quote-fails)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just need to surround your String with triple-double quotes:

```
scala>  s"""${x}""""
res1: String = 5"
```